# Break Array Values Into New Line in Angular

Tags: javascript, arrays, json, angular

How can i break this array of errors into new line? I tried using "\n" and it doesn't break into lines in Angular?

> JSON

```
{
  "headers": {
    "normalizedNames": {},
    "lazyUpdate": null
  },
  "status": 404,
  "statusText": "Not Found",
  "url": "http://sample.com",
  "ok": false,
  "name": "HttpErrorResponse",
  "message": "Http failure response for http://sample.com: 404 Not Found",
  "error": {
    "error": [
      "Error1",
      "Error2",
      "Error3"
    ]
  }
}
```

> error.ts

```
error => {
             alert("ERROR" + "\n" +  error.error.error + "\n");    
             console.log(error.error.error);
          });
```

Comment: Are you placing the result in HTML? If so, you need to use `<br>` instead.

Comment: Have you tried `<br/>`? Where exactly are you displaying this? `\n` works in `alert`s.

Comment: @Xufox instead of `<br/>` its better to use an element like `<p>` or `<span style='display:block'>`.

Comment: The word "error breaks but the error1, error2, error3 doesnt break line

Comment: @HassanImam. It says e.join is not a function

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem is that `error.error.error` in an array and you are printing it as it is.

Try this

```js
var error = {
"headers": {
 "normalizedNames": {},
 "lazyUpdate": null
},
"status": 404,
"statusText": "Not Found",
"url": "http://sample.com",
"ok": false,
"name": "HttpErrorResponse",
"message": "Http failure response for http://sample.com: 404 Not Found",
"error": {
 "error": [
 "Error1",
 "Error2",
 "Error3"
 ]
}
}
var alertString = 'error ';
for (var i = 0; i < error.error.error.length; i++) {
alertString = alertString + '\n ' + error.error.error[i];
}
alert(alertString);
 console.log(alertString);
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use `array#join()` with `<br>` to insert breakline when displaying error in HTML page. When you want to display error in `alert()` or `console` you can `array#join('\n')`.

```js
var error = {"headers":{"normalizedNames":{},"lazyUpdate":null},"status":404,"statusText":"Not Found","url":"http://sample.com","ok":false,"name":"HttpErrorResponse","message":"Http failure response for http://sample.com: 404 Not Found","error":{"error":["Error1","Error2","Error3"]}}
alert(error.error.error.join('\n'));
document.write(error.error.error.join('<br>'));
```

Answer (score 0):

Persist error in component file and iterate the same in HTML

TS file

```
error : any ={
  "headers": {
    "normalizedNames": {},
    "lazyUpdate": null
  },
  "status": 404,
  "statusText": "Not Found",
  "url": "http://sample.com",
  "ok": false,
  "name": "HttpErrorResponse",
  "message": "Http failure response for http://sample.com: 404 Not Found",
  "error": {
    "error": [
      "Error1",
      "Error2",
      "Error3"
    ]
  }
}
```

HTML file

```
<div *ngFor="let err of error.error.error">{{err}}</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this code bro,

```
error => {
             alert("ERROR" + "\n" +  error.error[0] + "\n" +  error.error[1] + "\n" +  error.error[2]);    
             console.log(error.error);
          });
```